# Is there any merit in writing REST api in CXF/jax-rs over spring mvc?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, cxf, jax-rs

Having implemented REST apis in spring-mvc, I was looking into some code that uses CXF+jaxrs and was wondering if there could be some specific scenarios where use of cxf+jaxrs be preferred over spring-mvc. The neatness and ease of learning of spring-mvc are absolute winners for me but my view is most probably biased , hence I am seeking out for unbiased views on this one.

Comment: When most people say "REST", I think they really mean "JSON" and "GET-able" ..

Comment: i mean the whole stuff here not just JSON GET :)